# How do I decode HTML data with Swiftsoup into a struct and print that said struct?

Tags: swift, networking, swiftsoup

I am trying to create a Network Manager which firstly requests a GET request to a aspx login form. In order to perform a login obviously I need to later on put a POST with a username/password but also a ViewState and ViewState Generator. I am trying to extract the last two named variables and I would like to store them in a Struct. I'm quite stuck on the last step.

Below you can find a code snipped:

NetworkingManager.swift:

```
final class NetworkingManager {
    
    static let shared = NetworkingManager()
  
    private init() {}
    
    func request(_ absoluteURL: String) {
        
        
        let url = URL(string: "https://examplelink.com")
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        
        let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            
            if error != nil { return }
            
            guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                  (200...300) ~= response.statusCode else { return }
            
            guard let data = data else { return }
            
            do {
                let tempHTML = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
                let viewState = try! SwiftSoup.parse(tempHTML!).select("input[name=__VIEWSTATE]").attr("value")
                let viewStateGenerator = try! SwiftSoup.parse(tempHTML!).select("input[name=__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR").attr("value")
                
                var tokens = viewstateToken(viewState: viewState, viewStateGenerator: viewStateGenerator)
    
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
           
        }
        dataTask.resume()
        
    }
}
```

viewStateToken.swift:

```
struct viewstateToken: Identifiable, Hashable, Codable {

    let id = UUID()
    var viewState: String
    var viewStateGenerator: String
    
}
```

I got through that I am able to get the variables I need and I am able to store them into viewStateToken struct, however when I try to print what is in the struct I am unable to.

This is on my ContentView when the code runs:

```
 .onAppear {
            NetworkingManager.shared.request("https://examplelink.com")
            
        }
```

Inside the onAppear I would like to print the viewstatetoken data in order to verify that there indeed is data stored and useable later on in the POST request.

Comment: Where do you try to print? Your function doesn’t return any value nor does it update any property in the class so it’s unclear what the issue is.

Comment: Sorry about that, I will try to clarify. 

I try to save the tokens in the tokens variable, which should save into the viewStateToken struct. I would like to try to print the view state token struct values in the console. 

So I can check whether the variables are indeed there.

Comment: But `tokens` is a local variable, it will disappear as soon as the execution leaves the `do {...}` scope which is directly. So this is about understanding scope and lifetime of variables and either how to return data from an asynchronous call or how to handle data in SwiftUI using the ObservableObject protocol.